# 'juju status -e maas --debug' showing connection refused

Tags: juju, maas

while trying to query status of an  environment i am getting the following errors.

```
juju status --debug
2016-03-31 09:44:05 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:337 error dialing "wss://10.1.0.11:17070/environment/b61d8832-5b0a-43cd-8447-c70b33caf157/api", will retry: websocket.Dial wss://10.1.0.11:17070/environment/b61d8832-5b0a-43cd-8447-c70b33caf157/api: dial tcp 10.1.0.11:17070: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding rules to iptables

```
  sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

`iptables -A FORWARD -i <interface without internet> -o <interface with internet> -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A FORWARD -i <interface with internet> -o <interface without internet> -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <interface with internet> -j MASQUERADE`